# git branch dependency, how to push a certain brach

Tags: git

I have a git branch related question.

For example, from the origin/master codebase, I switch to a branch, `b1`:

```
git checkout -b b1
```

Here, I update the code, then commit the changes.

Then, I switch to another branch, `b2`:

```
git checkout -b b2
```

Here, `b2` depends on `b1`,  `b2` can see `b1`'s changes; so based on `b1`'s code, I further modify the code-base, commit the changes.

My question is: Can I just push the code change in `b2`, without the changes in `b1`?

Note: in my condition, I don't want to push the changes in b1.

Thanks

Comment: Question here... Couldn't you just revert the changes you don't want to have in the master branch that are present in b1 branch? If so, then instead of creating a sub-branch of b1, 'b2', you just merge b1 (without the code you'd like to omit) directly to master.

Comment: [Very similar question asked recently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144367/git-branching-pull-request-on-head-branch-takes-also-prior-branch-commits/50144819)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly: you need to replay b2 on top of origin/master (assuming that none of b2 change depends on b1 changes, or your prooject won't compile)

```
git checkout b2
git rebase --onto origin/master b1
git push
# if you had already pushed b2:
git push --force
```

Note that if b2 was already pushed and used by other collaborator, that would rewrite its history: you need to warn your colleagues.